# Where to find ancient wavy cursor program 'cyclops'?

Tags: bbs

In the period of about 1987-1988 I downloaded a small compiled program from a BBS in the 512 area. I don't know anything about the author but the file was named 'cyclops.' I can't be sure if it had a .com or .exe extension. Possibly it could have been named 'cycleops.' I know it's file size was exactly 255 bytes. It was a TSR program that animated the DOS cursor making it appear as a single horizontal line slowly rising and falling in place of the blinking cursor. People who saw it often said it made them feel dizzy to watch it. Can anyone direct me on where I might find this again? I have made several search attempts that yielded no clues.

Comment: I don't recall this program in particular, but you might find it if you look for BBS archives. One in particular is The Cave BBS (which is still online via telnet), but the file section is online at ftp://ftp3.us.freebsd.org/pub/misc/dos/cavebbs/

Comment: 1988 is "ancient"?!  Hmmmph.

Comment: It's like saying the Internet is just a bunch of BBS. Aside from being true in some sense, it just sounds about right. Ask kids today if they've heard of Ronald Reagan. Chances are they'll say "Oh yeah, ancient grease." And they'd be about right, wouldn't they?

Comment: Anyway, still looking for that program, cyclops.com (or .exe). Somebody must have it.  It could have been renamed but it would still be exactly 255 bytes on disk. Check your old floppies, BBS archives, etc., maybe listed as cursor or utility.